# Query en Request Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

He estado tratando de realizar una consulta dentro de mi request en Laravel. Mi sistema es para un control de inventarios. Cuando se solicita cierta cantidad de piezas de algún modelo, estas son sacadas de contenedores llamados 'Palets'. Lo que quiero hacer es evitar que me deje inventarios negativos. Supongamos que necesito sacar 10,000 piezas del palet 5, pero únicamente tengo 5,000. El sistema actualmente me deja sacar las 10,000 pero me deja un saldo restante en el palet de -5,000 piezas.

El request:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use DB;

class requestValidadorRequisicion1 extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'request_No' => 'required',
            'amount_Pieces' => 'required',
            'pallet_No' => 'required',
        ];
    }
    public function withValidator($validadorEI)
    {
        $validadorEI->after(function ($validadorEI) {

            $cantidadPiezasPalet = DB::table('info_palet')
                ->select('No_Piezas')
                ->where('No_Palet_FK', '=' , $this->pallet_No);


            if($this->amount_Pieces > $cantidadPiezasPalet){
                $validadorEI->errors()->add('saldoInsuficiente', 'Oops... No hay suficientes piezas.');
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer con esta consulta es decirle que seleccione la cantidad de piezas donde el número del palet sea igual al seleccionado anteriormente.

Si la cantidad requerida es menor a la existente en la BD no debería de haber ningún problema, pero si es mayor quiero que me impida realizar la operación, puesto que me está dejando los saldos en el almacén negativos. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anexo una imagen de la tabla que estoy usando en la BD.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consulta en DB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agregarías tu consulta a la base de datos?

Comment: Claro que si amigo, la pondré al final de la publicación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, según la documentación te falta agregar el método para obtener los registros de la base de datos: "get();"

```
$cantidadPiezasPalet = DB::table('info_palet')
            ->select('No_Piezas')
            ->where('No_Palet_FK', '=' , $this->pallet_No)
            ->get();
```

Esto devuelve un arreglo de resultados por lo tanto es necesario hacer uso del foreach para recorrerlo aunque solo traiga un registro.

La forma mas optima de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
 $cantidadPiezasPalet = DB::table('info_palet')
                        ->where('No_Palet_FK', $this->pallet_No)
                        ->value('No_Piezas');
```

De esta manera si podras realizar la evaluacion tal y como tu lo tienes ahorita

```
      if($this->amount_Pieces > $cantidadPiezasPalet){
            $validadorEI->errors()->add('saldoInsuficiente', 'Oops... No hay suficientes piezas.');
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda amigo, lo he probado pero tengo un problema. En mi BD manejo muchos palets, y a la hora de realizar la operación de sacar piezas e internamente en la BD se efectúa la resta correspondiente. Los demás palets se ven afectados. Si en un palet saco 100 piezas los demas palets los coloca en 0.

Comment: Podrías agregar el query donde realizas el descuento. Puede que el problema sea alli.

Comment: Las restas lo estoy haciendo mediante disparadores en la BD. Buscaré el error ahí, pero me podrías explicar en la query, cual es la función del value por favor.

Comment: La funcion "value()" funciona para traer únicamente el valor de una columna de tu tabla y no el registro completo, para este caso le decimos que traiga el valor del campo "No_Piezas".

Comment: Amigo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tu query corregida fue mi solución. Sí había algunos disparadores defectuosos pero arreglandolos quedó de lujo. Muchas gracias en verdad por tu ayuda. Tenía mucho tiempo en ello y no quedaba :c

Answer (score 0):

Al margen de otras respuestas que te ofrezcan, considero que lo mas simple es manejar esto a nivel del mismo controlador donde tienes tu consulta para ni involucrar al *form request* donde solo puedes dejar las validaciones de la *data proveniente del frontend* es decir:

```
$minimoStock = Modelo::select('No_Piezas')
                     ->where(......)//tu otra condición
                     ->first();
```

En lo anterior:

- Obtenemos el actual del stock asignándolo a una variable
- Usaremos esta variable para hacer una comparación posterior

De modo que ahora podemos hacer una comparación con una estructura `if/else` con el *operador ternario* para que:

- Si el sock actual en la base de datos es mayor al solicitado entonces se atiende dicha petición
- En caso de que el stock actual es menor o igual al solicitado entonces se niega la petición

Propuesta

```
$minimoStock   = Modelo::select('No_Piezas')->first();
$peticionStock = $request->valor;



$consulta = ($minimoStock->No_Piezas > $peticionStock) 
                    ? Modelo::select('........')->get() 
                    : response()->json(["message" => "Sin stock suficiente oara atenderte"]);
```

Lo que hicimos fue:

- Valido si la petición es mayor a la existencia real, entonces procedo con la consulta
- En caso de que la existencia sea menor a la solicitada entonces retorno como json un mensaje con la clave **message** que después puedes manipular en la vista

**Referencias**

- [json responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#json-responses)